# this.props is undefined inside click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Hi I have the following react component.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';

const propTypes = {
    /*
     * Used to extend default object classes
     */
    classes : PropTypes.object,

    /*
     * Click event handler
     */
    onClick : PropTypes.func,

    /*
     * Delete event handler
     */
    onRequestDelete : PropTypes.func,

    /*
     * This property will contain label text
     */
    label : PropTypes.string
}

class Chip extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    onClick(e) {
        if (this.props.disabled) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return;
        }

        if (this.props.onClick) {
          this.props.onClick(e);
        }
    }

    handleDeleteIconClick(e){
        e.stopPropagation();

        if (this.props.onRequestDelete) {
          this.props.onRequestDelete(event);
        }
    };

    render(){

        let defaultClasses = 'chips chips-rounded';

        const {
            classes,
            onClick,
            label,
            onRequestDelete,
        } = this.props;

        return (

            <div
                className={classNames(classes, defaultClasses)}
                onClick={onClick}
            >
                <span className={classes}>{label}</span>
                {onRequestDelete ? (<div className="deleteIcon" onClick={ this.handleDeleteIconClick } />) : ''}
            </div>

        )
    }

}

Chip.PropTypes = propTypes;

export default Chip
```

when I run the component and trigger the `handleDeleteIconClick` event I get the following error. What am I doing wrong here.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
    at handleDeleteIconClick (1.a0d91201f90f20151e22.hot-update.js:86)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.boundFunc (main.bundle.js:8934)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (main.bundle.js:8940)
    at executeDispatch (main.bundle.js:8725)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (main.bundle.js:8748)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (main.bundle.js:5786)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (main.bundle.js:5797)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at forEachAccumulated (main.bundle.js:13425)
    at Object.processEventQueue (main.bundle.js:5997)
```

Comment: are you binding `handleDeleteIconClick` ?

Comment: yes I bind it to the `deleteIcon` element in the return statement.

Comment: inside constructor you are binding `this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);` can't see `habdleDeleteonClick` anywhere in the code

Comment: when I add the binding code, it throws a `ReferenceError` saying the `handleDeleteIconClick` is not defined.

Comment: i am assuming you are binding it inside constructor like `this.handleDeleteonClick = this.handleDeleteonClick.bind(this);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bind the context to handleDeleteIconClick in constructor like,

```
this.handleDeleteIconClick = this.handleDeleteIconClick.bind(this);
```

or put this `handleDeleteIconClick.bind(this)` in yor JSX,
because you use keyword this in that function

Comment: when I use your code, I get the error `ReferenceError: handleDeleteIconClick is not defined`

Comment: this.handleDeleteIconClick = this.handleDeleteIconClick.bind(this); I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the fat arrow function like `handleDeleteIconClick = (e) => {/* function logic */}`. In this case, you don't need to bind the function in constructor and `this` will be available within the function with correct scope.